# Lion "hosts" File Bug

Tags: macos, hosts

I have some serious problems with the hosts file on my Lion 10.7.2. My hosts file is like following;

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

27.0.0.1 first.localhost
::1 first.localhost
27.0.0.1 second.localhost
::1 second.localhost
```

I have more than 2 local sites but I just cut is short.

I can't manage `http://first.localhost/` to work. `http://second.localhost/` works fine but `http://first.localhost/` doesn't work. If I delete the last two lines (which corresponds to **second**) than `http://first.localhost/` works.

How can I add more than one local site in my hosts file? I'm using Lion 10.7.2 which I upgraded today and all those problems arose after that upgrade.

**Note:** There is nothing wrong with Apache config files or any other file with the local web server, I know that it's the `/etc/hosts` file that causes the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what exactly the problem was. TextMate was *appending*? As opposed to what? What did nano do that TextMate wasn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All additional entries to the HOSTS file must be above the:

```
fe80::1%lo0
```

Make sure there is at least one line break after the last entry. Like so:

```
127.0.0.1 LLL.localhost
127.0.0.1 LLL.localhost
#
```

Although you probably can't tell, there is another line following the # symbol. One more thing to mention, using <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> between 127.0.0.1 and localhost might help too.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uuDzA9pT this is how my `hosts` file looks like but `test.example.com` not working. I read some articles that advise the same you say but nothing's working.

Comment: I'll take a look, just one sec.

Comment: Try this one: http://pastebin.com/d01ahHss ( just replace the XYZ.localhost with yours )

Comment: Not working :( This works; http://pastebin.com/g8b6AnZ9 but can't add a second vhost. If there is only one site, than the one that I wrote works, but if I try to add more sites it doesn't work. This is the weirdest OSX bug I've ever seen :)

Comment: Everything MUST be above the line: fe80::1%lo0

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code but didn't work. The one that I've posted works but as I said, I can't add another site.

Comment: Also, don't use tabs between 127.0.0.1 and localhost either; that can cause problems. http://pastebin.com/fGzJxzHT

Comment: I'm just copy/pasting your code. Nothing more, nothing less but not working. So those work for you? What's you Lion version?

Comment: ah, I thought you were editing your hosts file. you need to change the first, second, etc. http://pastebin.com/zd4E4j62

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1571/discussion-between-ioi-and-burak-erdem)

Comment: It was a simple file editing issue. I was just appending my hosts file while editing with `Textmate`. Editing with `nano` solved the problem. Thanks @ioi for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to follow ioi's answer to the T to get this to work correctly.  I think the real trick might be the extra line at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes but it was my fault that I edited `hosts` file with Textmate and I didn't realize that TM was appending the file. Using `nano` solved the problem, thanks to @ioi.

Comment: @c-apolzon — I agree. It definitely doesn't hurt to ensure EOF.