# How set up a local domain such as local.test?

Tags: network, development, hosts

I'm web-developer and I need local domains. Before 10.7.2 update, I'm just fix /etc/hosts as I need, but new update crash this solution. How fix this new "feature"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lion "hosts" File Bug](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27415/lion-hosts-file-bug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27415/lion-hosts-file-bug/27417#27417) on the question [Lion “hosts” File Bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27415/lion-hosts-file-bug) is relevant here as well.

All additional entries to the HOSTS file must be above the:

```
fe80::1%lo0
```

Make sure there is at least one line break after the last entry. Like so:

```
127.0.0.1 LLL.localhost
127.0.0.1 LLL.localhost
#
```

Although you probably can't tell, there is another line following the # symbol. One more thing to mention, using <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> between 127.0.0.1 and localhost might help too.