# osx hosts file not working

Tags: macos, hosts

my hosts file looks like this

it should open facebook if you try to open google

```
173.252.110.27 google.com
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

also after I added that first line I did:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

on a OSX 10.8.5 but it doesn't changes anything.

I searched for a while and found different things none helped me.

On this link: [Hosts file in OSX Lion not blocking as expected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/hosts-file-in-osx-lion-not-blocking-as-expected) there is a good answer but I don't know how to check which file format I have.

So the question is: 
- is there something wrong with my hosts file?
- how do I check which file format I've got

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hosts file does not support wildcards, so you have to map each domain and subdomain,
which means, you need to add

```
173.252.110.27   www.google.com
```

as well. If you are redirect to a local version of google, eg like www.google.fr, you need to add that as well.

You can edit the host file easily from a terminal window without changing the file format to RichText or similar by running the following command:

```
$ sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

You need to enter your password. Afterwards, add your changes at the end of the file, not the beginning.

At the end, flush you DNS cache or reboot your mac.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it still doesn't work. I've edited the hosts file with vi, should be the same as nano? also now it is at the end. didn't reboot my mac yet but tried with the above flush cache

Comment: vi should be ok. Flushing only the DNS cache should be ok as well. Did you restart your web client  / browser?

Comment: now it works, tried for hours, restarting the browser and adding it to the end as you mentioned did the trick... thanks!

Comment: Actually, `google.com` isn't a wildcard. `*.google.com` would be.